# Google Sheets GAS: Setting formula to a Cell with Date criteria Data Validation

Tags: validation, datetime, google-apps-script

Good day,

I have a "client" sheet that has a column with Data Validation criteria **Date** in order for the user to have a date picker.

However, if a date already exists in the main "database" sheet, I want to read the date into the same cell in the "client" sheet that has the Data Validation.

I do so be adding a formula to the cell which reads data from the corresponding cell in the IMPORTRANGE I used to get data from the "database" sheet.

After a user selects a date (overwriting the formula), I want to now reset the value of the cell to the formula that references the IMPORTRANGE. However, when doing so, I get the following error from the Date Data Validation:

```
Mar 4, 2021, 10:00:37 AM    Error   Exception: Enter a valid date
```

I have tried both setValue() and setFormula() methods but I'm still getting the same error.

```
  var expiresCell = sheet.getRange(clientVehiclePermits.expiresColName+row);
  if (expiresCell.getFormula()===""){
    expiresCell.setFormula("="+ clientVehiclePermits.db_expiresColName+row);
  }
```

Is there any way I can set the forumla of a cell and maintain the Date data validation?

Will appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `I want to read the date into the same cell in the "client" sheet that has the Data Validation`. Could you please clarify about this. It might be useful to provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information).

Comment: Hi lambilchus, I did a work around by removing the validation from apps script, setting the formula value to the cell, then reinstating the validation on the cell using the setDataValidation(null) method. I've been working on a CRUD interface on sheets, will take some time to share it as there some personal information on it. Once I'm done I will share my workings ... basically the "client sheet" has a data sheet that IMPORTRANGEs from the main "database" Spreadsheet, and a UI sheet that has filters above and can edit the data.

Comment: You mean you found a workaround that solves your issue?

Comment: yes I just removed the data validation, set the cell to the formula I wanted, then re-applied the same data validation.

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer explaining how you solved this issue?